# Wpf Conditional PreviewMouseDown

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I've got a WPF template for a ListBox where each ListBoxItem contains a button.

The ListBoxItem handles a PreviewMouseDown event. The button inside the ListBoxItem has a click event. I'm using MVVM with Caliburn.Micro.

What I'd like to happen is for PreviewMouseDown to get ignored by ListBoxItem when the user is clicking the button. Based on my understanding though since PreviewMouseDown "Tunnels Down" rather than Bubbling Up, there's no way to capture that event on the Visual Tree at the button level. And, since the event is handled in a ViewModel I'd like to avoid logic like "If UIElement is a button, ignore PreviewMouseDown" since that would presuppose a certain type of view.

Is there a way to have ListBoxItem execute PreviewMouseDown conditionally only when the user isn't clicking the button?

Edit: (I'm using cal:Message.Attach in the View for ListBoxItem to attach a command to a method on the ViewModel, so there is no code behind)

Comment: Why do you have a PreviewMouseDown on the item in the first place? If you're using MVVM you should theoretically have no code-behind, which is why I ask.

Comment: I might have worded that badly. I'm using cal:Message.Attach to attach a command to a method on the VM like this:

cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseDown] = [Action MyFirstMethod($dataContext)]; [Event PreviewMouseUp] = [Action MySecondMethod()]   

(Come to think of it I need to block PreviewMouseUp as well!)

So, there is no code-behind.

Comment: if you have no problem with anti-patterns you can pass the $eventArgs to your ViewModel and mark it as Handled = true;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Create a Behavior and attach it to the ListBox-Control in Xaml. Within the behavior register to the preview event of the ListBox. In the registered EventHandler set e.Handled on the event to true.

If you have access to the ListBoxItem, you can also attach a behavior to the items directly.